# Why css animation dose not work on external elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

the following code is working fine

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" />
</div>
```

but if i place the img tag outside of the wrapper then the code not works
so in that case what can i do?
but if i place the img tag outside of the wrapper then the code not works
so in that case what can i do?
but if i place the img tag outside of the wrapper then the code not works
so in that case what can i do?

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
    </div>

<img id="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" />
</html>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: .wrapper:hover #slide only works if #slide is inside .wrapper - pretty simple really - you could try `.wrapper:hover + #slide`, or rethink the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sibling selector `+`:

```
.wrapper:hover + #slide
```

Example:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover + #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="wrapper">
    </div>

<img id="slide" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-4.jpg" />
</html>
```